# List enumerated with multi-line stuff inside a minipage

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, minipage, enumitem, mathtools

I have created a list using `enumitem` package. The items of the list should be enumerated with multi-line blocks of text, like this

[image]

As I haven't found a way to pass `item` more than one argument I just pass a `minipage`. The problem is with the alignement:
[image]

I want the text to be aligned with the word "Problem", i. e. blue line to be aligned with the red one. But passing `[t]` argument to the `minipage` gives me errors.

**UPDATE.** After passing `[t]` option to minipage the next line of the item is to low and a space is added before the first letter:

[image]

Here is my MWE

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} %uncomment to test if everything us ok (requires Lua)

\newcounter{problemscounter}

\newlength{\LABELWIDTH}

\newenvironment{problems}{
    \begin{list}{}%
        {
            \usecounter{problemscounter}
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{3cm}
            \setlength{\LABELWIDTH}{\labelwidth}
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{12pt}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
            \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
            \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
        } 
    }{ 
    \end{list}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\TT}{mmm}{
        \item[{%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\LABELWIDTH}
                \textbf{%
                    \textup{%
                        Problem\kern.4em\ignorespaces\stepcounter{problemscounter}\arabic{problemscounter}.%
                    }%
                }\\
                \textit{#1 point#2}.\\%
                #3.
            \end{minipage}
        }]%
    }


\begin{document}

    \begin{problems}

        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory} \lipsum[1]

        \TT{2}{s}{Mandatory} More difficult one.

        \TT{2017}{s}{Bonus} Good luck solving this.

    \end{problems}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a list or may I change something?

Comment: @TeXnician you want to make a `tabular`?

Comment: Actually not, although this would be another option, I would mess with minipages only.

Comment: @TeXnician It doesn't need to be list, really. I just want it to look like this and to be "splittable" over pages (not like tabular).

Comment: You need to `\smash` the tag, as in `\NewDocumentCommand{\TT}{mmm}{
        \item[{\smash{...}]}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the vertical spacing is fixed, but there is still a horizontal space and minipage in problem 2 is now on top of problem 3.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I tried that. That does not work. There's no space for points and "mandatory".

Comment: @TeXnician There is a basic conflict here...the label takes 3 lines.  If the question is less than 3 lines, you want it to occupy that as a minimum or the overlap occurs.  On the other hand, if you explicitly make the label appear 3 lines tall, it interferes with spacing of any answer greater than a single line.  You can fix one issue, but not both simultaneously, using an `\item` approach.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I know, therefore my answer does not use items.

Comment: @TeXnician Well one *could* use items if one sets `\itemsep` larger, for example `26 pt`.  However, one has then to live with lots of white space.  Alternately, create a macro `\skiplines{}` to add at the end of short items to skip one or two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the list as you had it (although I added some missing `%`) but hide the height of the minipage. Then to avoid the three line item label overprinting when the paragraph is short, check `\prevgraf` (the number of lines) at the end of the paragraph and add one or two blank lines if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} %uncomment to test if everything us ok (requires Lua)

\newcounter{problemscounter}

\newlength{\LABELWIDTH}

\newenvironment{problems}{%
    \begin{list}{}%
        {%
            \usecounter{problemscounter}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{3cm}%
            \setlength{\LABELWIDTH}{\labelwidth}%
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
            \setlength{\itemsep}{12pt}%
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}%
            \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}%
            \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}%
        }%
    }{%
    \par
    \end{list}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\TT}{mmm}{%
        \par
        \item[{%
            \begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\LABELWIDTH}%
                \textbf{%
                    \textup{%
                        Problem\kern.4em\ignorespaces\stepcounter{problemscounter}\arabic{problemscounter}.%
                    }%
                }\\%
                \textit{#1 point#2}.\\%
                #3.%
            \end{minipage}%
        }]%
    \everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar
     \let\svpar\par
     \let\par\TTpar}%
    }%


\newcommand\TTpar{%
\let\par\svpar
\par
\ifcase\prevgraf
\or%0
\mbox{}\\*\mbox{}\par\or%1
\mbox{}\par
\fi}

\begin{document}

    \begin{problems}

        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory} \lipsum[1]

        \TT{2}{s}{Mandatory} More difficult one.

        \TT{2017}{s}{Bonus} Good luck solving this.

    \end{problems}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tricy solution, but very good. Your code, in fact, has some strange stiff after `\end{document}`. I guess it is not needed.

Comment: fortunately, nothing after the end is read, so it is a working code)

Comment: @MichaelFreimann fixed now:-)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into braces. Using braces you can even use optional arguments (which would end the optional argument of `\item` the other way). Then your approach with `t` works.

*Background:* If you want to use `\item` it scans for an optional argument started with `[` and ended with `]`. That means if you put a `minipage` in there that uses `[t]` `item`'s scan for a closing bracket says HERE and ends the optional item. It should be clear that this is neither intended not able to work. Braces on the other hand form a group that can "mask" such bad characters, what enables optional arguments in optional arguments.

[image: problems]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}

%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} %uncomment to test if everything is ok (requires Lua)

\newcounter{problemscounter}

\newlength{\LABELWIDTH}

\newenvironment{problems}{
    \begin{list}{}%
        {
            \usecounter{problemscounter}
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{3cm}
            \setlength{\LABELWIDTH}{\labelwidth} %Will be passed to minipage
            \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{12pt}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
            \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
            \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
        } 
    }{ 
    \end{list}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\TT}{mmm}{
        \item[{%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\LABELWIDTH}
                \textbf{%
                    \textup{%
                        Problem\kern.4em\ignorespaces\stepcounter{problemscounter}\arabic{problemscounter}.%
                    }%
                }\\
                \textit{#1 point#2}.\\%
                #3.
            \end{minipage}
        }]%
    }


\begin{document}

    \begin{problems}

        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory} The first problem.

        \TT{2}{s}{Mandatory} More difficult one.

        \TT{2017}{s}{Bonus} Good luck solving this.

    \end{problems}

\end{document}
```

*Update 1:* A solution completely without environment, but with one additional parameter.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{problemscounter}

\newlength{\LABELWIDTH}
\setlength{\LABELWIDTH}{3cm}
\newlength{\LABELSEP}
\setlength{\LABELSEP}{.5em}


\NewDocumentCommand{\TT}{mmm +m}{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\LABELWIDTH}
            \textbf{%
               \textup{%
                    Problem\kern.4em\ignorespaces\stepcounter{problemscounter}\arabic{problemscounter}.%
                }%
            }\\
            \textit{#1 point#2}.\\%
            #3.
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\LABELWIDTH-\LABELSEP}\setlength{\parindent}{1em}\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
            #4
      \end{minipage}\par\vskip12pt
    }


\begin{document}

        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory}{\lipsum[1]}

        \TT{2}{s}{Mandatory}{More difficult one.}

        \TT{2017}{s}{Bonus}{Good luck solving this.}
        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory}{\lipsum[1]}
        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory}{\lipsum[1]}
        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory}{\lipsum[1]}
        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory}{\lipsum[1]}
        \TT{1}{}{Mandatory}{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

*Update 2:* Another approach to think of is using `ltablex` or similar, which allow automatic text width columns (like`p{3cm}X`) and page breaking. I won't elaborate on this, because it's a very tricky approach. I would recommend the non-list version.

Comment: It works, thx. Can you please explain why does this happed?

Comment: I haven't properly researched the question, thus a new spacing problem appeared. I have updated the question.

Comment: the new one is good, though `minipage` cannot split over pages, unfortunately. If you do `\TT{1}{}{Mandatory}{\lipsum[1-15]}` it causes a bad output. I hope I will not be using such long texts.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann Well hanging also doesn't work. It's currently the best that I can do.

Comment: well, thanks a lot, I will stick with this one for now.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, the list making environment has issues depending on whether the label is higher (deeper) or shorter than the item body.  Fixing one way breaks the other way,e tc.  Thus, here I adopt a `tabular` approach.

I also use stacks instead of a `minipage` to construct the label.  I wrap it all in the original `problems` environment proposed by the OP.  However, instead of using `\item`, instead set it up like a `tabular`, as follows:

```
\begin{problems}
    \TT{1}{Mandatory} &\lipsum[1]\par\lipsum[2]\\
    \TT{2}{Mandatory} & More difficult one.\\
    \TT{2017}{Bonus} & Good luck solving this.
\end{problems}
```

Finally, I eliminate the need to specify the suffix on "point".  I just check to see if the value equals 1; if not, I add an "s" suffix.

EDITED to use `longtable` in support of page breaks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{tabularx,longtable}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} %uncomment to test if everything us ok (requires Lua)

\newcounter{problemscounter}

\newlength{\LABELWIDTH}
\setlength{\LABELWIDTH}{3cm}
\newenvironment{problems}{\noindent\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}%
  \begin{longtable}{c>{\parskip 1ex}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-\LABELWIDTH}}
    }{ 
    \end{longtable}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TT}{mm}{\stepcounter{problemscounter}%
        {\Longunderstack[l]{%
                \textbf{\textup{Problem\kern.4em\arabic{problemscounter}.}}\\
                \textit{#1 point\ifnum#1=1\relax\else s\fi}.\\%
                #2.}
        }%
    }
\newcommand\skipline{\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\newcommand\skiplines{\vspace{2\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{problems}
        \TT{1}{Mandatory} &\lipsum[1]\par\lipsum[2]\\
        \TT{2}{Mandatory} & More difficult one.\\
        \TT{2017}{Bonus} & Good luck solving this.\\
        \TT{1000}{Ausgezeichnet} & Testing page breaks.
                 \lipsum[3-5]\\
        \TT{2000}{Ausgezeichnet} & Testing page breaks.
                 \lipsum[4-6]
    \end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it page breaking as the OP wants?

Comment: @TeXnician No it does not...I did not see that requirement.  Perhaps I can get around to making it a longtable.

Comment: Good luck. I tried that (to be fair with `ltablex` and one `X` column) and it was disastrous. Hopefully yours will work.

Comment: @TeXnician Added `\usepackage{longtable}` and changed `tabular` to `longtable` and everything worked.  Which is to say an overrunning row will break completely to the next page, though a row itself will not be broken up.